# Measures of interdependence of events of different types

Tags: modeling, stochastic-processes, markov-process, recurrent-events

A mouse does four things: eats (E), drinks (D), defecates (S), and urinates (U). A time chart records the occurrence of each event along with the time in minutes (after the commencement of measurement) at which the event occurred. The time-chart actually has around 12,000 events of which the following is a sample.

```
S, 5
D, 9
S, 14
S, 17
D, 17
D, 21
E, 23
U, 28
D, 31
E, 33
E, 36
U, 37
E, 39
D, 39
D, 39
S, 42
E, 46
U, 49
D, 51
S, 52
```

As you can see, there might be no obvious ordering to the events and one event type might be followed by another event of the same type. I’m interested to discover something about the possible interdependence of events. For example, defecation (S) might be presumed to be stimulated by eating (E), but there is also the possibility that the reverse is true and that S leads to sensations of emptiness that then promote an increased likelihood of E. In case it is not clear, I'm not just interested in the frequency of the immediately following events. For example, S might stimulate E, irrespective of any intervening D or U events.

At this stage, I don’t know how to phrase my question better than that. I would appreciate advice on: (a) whether there is a standard expression or phrase to describe the problem I am faced with … so that I can do a sensible search, (b) improving the question (!), and (c) measures and calculation. I can always re-edit and improve my question in the light of new information!

Comment: 1. Please correct the count in your first sentence. Presumably you mean four things. 2. You should make explicit whether the time variable is the time at which it occurs or how long it occurs for. For convenience it would help to give units (seconds after the start of the observation period?). 3. "Interested to discover something" is pretty broad, perhaps too broad for a suitable question. Can you be any more precise? Note that if you're "just trying to find anything" you can't really talk about significance very meaningfully (or get unbiased effect estimates) unless you sample split ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... using part of the data to formulate models or hypotheses and the remainder to estimate or assess them.

Comment: Many thanks @Glen_b for the helpful comments. I have corrected the errors and, I hope, made the description clearer. By "discover something about the interdependence of events", I (probably) mean something like "does the occurrence of event type X decrease the time it would otherwise take for event type Y to occur?". There must, simply because of the most basic causation model, be a relationship between E and S, as well as D and U. Absent E altogether, and S will never occur; absent D, U will not occur ... and the mouse will die. But what more can I say?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a multi-state Markov process in continuous time, with four states (and maybe a fifth for *something else*?)  [Here](https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~titman/leeds_seminar.pdf) is an introduction, and there is an R package [msm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/vignettes/msm-manual.pdf).